# Prompt user to login to wallet

Tags: metamask

The user has a wallet installed and but they are not logged in

the below function **does not** prompt the user login to their wallet, it just returns an empty array.

```
  const getAccount = async () => {
    try {
      const acc = await window.ethereum.request({
        method: 'eth_accounts',
      });
      console.log(acc);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('err');
    }
  };
```

but if they don't have the chain I want to use installed **I do** get a prompt, why?

```
  const installAndChangeToNet = async (): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      await window.ethereum.request({
        method: 'wallet_addEthereumChain',
        params: [
          {
            chainId: chainId,
            chainName: chainName,
            nativeCurrency: {
              name: name,
              symbol: symbol,
              decimals: decimals,
            },
            rpcUrls: [rpcUrls],
            blockExplorerUrls: [blockExplorerUrls],
          },
        ],
      });
      getAccount();
    } catch (err: any) {
      alert('err');
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question, I think the problem is that you are calling the wrong method. If you look in the Metamask documentation, you can find this:

[Metamask Docs](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/getting-started.html#basic-considerations)

```
const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
const accounts = accounts[0];
```

So, with the first line, you request accounts from the connected wallet, and with the second line you already select the desired one.

That is, calling `eth_requestAccounts` gives access to the wallet and addresses.

Now, in the second one you call `wallet_addEthereumChain`. This method is used to add some particular network to the wallet, you can read more here in the [docs](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#wallet-addethereumchain)